# What are the minimal postulates of general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity

There exist two physical postulates of special relativity from which everything else follows as a consequence. These are: (1) the constancy of the speed of light in vacuum and (2) the form invariance of physical laws in all inertial frames. Every textbook lists out these two postulates and derives everything from them. Essentially everything (relativity of simultaneity, length contraction, time dilation, etc) follows from (1).

What are the minimal postulates of general relativity from which everything else follows? Surely, the equivalence principle, Einstein's equation, geodesic equation, and the principle of general covariance are part of it, I think. I am not sure how many independent physical inputs are required to formulate GR? How does curved spacetime fit into the postulates?

Comment: FWIW, Viktor Toth has a Quora answer [here](https://qr.ae/pGX0ki)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly For example, the relativity of simultaneity can be established/demonstrated on the basis of constancy of the speed of light in a vacuum, how do we deduce the inference that in presence of gravity, space-time is curved? The constancy of the speed of light enables us to deduce that moving clocks tick slower. How do we deduce that a gravitational field affects the rate at which clocks tick? What is that postulate which enables us to demonstrate light bends by a gravitational field?

Comment: Does the equivalence principle enough to deduce all these? After that how do we motivate the geodesic equation is the equation of motion for all particles? Is that too a postulate? Things are sort of jumbled up in my mind. How to logically read GR step by step having knowledge of special relativity. Should I regard it as a modification to SR to include accelerating frames or should I target learning this as a modification to Newton's theory of gravity?

Comment: How to learn GR in a logical progression of ideas? For example, when we replace $ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ to $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ without motivation, I am lost. Is that a postulate? Einstein's field equation is not derivable so that must be a postulate. Sorry for these long comments.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly This helps! Will you post these comments as answers?

Answer (score 2):

Hawking and Ellis give an axiomatization on pp. 58-61. Spacetime is a Hausdorff manifold with a nondegenerate metric that has signature +--- and satisfies certain conditions on integrability and differentiability. They also introduce the Einstein field equations and stress-energy tensor, and two postulates (causality and conservation of energy-momentum), but these are sort of vacuous unless you have some separate theory of the matter fields that you intend to plug in to GR.

Another approach is given by Andreka et al., "On logical analysis of relativity theories," Hungarian Philosophical Review, 2010/4, pp.204-222, http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0885 .

It doesn't really make sense to ask about "the" minimal postulates, both because GR can be formulated in multiple very different ways and because the same theory can always be axiomatized in many different ways.